# Django Queries to return a specific set of items

Tags: mysql, django

Here's a snippet of my code, it returns Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4 Product5 which are used to populate a drop down in the Webapp.

How would I get it to return only Product2 and Product4?

I was told to use the Queryset.filter method in another question I posted, but I'm not sure how to do it for multiple items?

and it turns out it's a mysql db (in my previous question I had thought it to be sqlite).

```
class Meta:
    model = ChangeRequest
    products = [(product.name, product.name) for product in Product.objects.all()]
    products = [('', '--------')] + products
    widgets = {
        'product': forms.Select(choices=products),
```

Comment: Under what criteria are you trying to filter? What attributes to product2 and product4 have? Are they a certain category, certain price etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only Product2 and Product4 you can do:

```
products = [Product.objects.get(name='Product2'), Product.objects.get(name='Product4')]
products = [(product.name, product.name) for product in products]
```

If this is not quite the answer you were expecting, please specify the criteria you'd like to filter your objects with.

Comment: `Product.objects.filter(name__in=['Product2', 'Product3', ...])` might be a little better as it will only generate one query